# Почему появились Словопоклонники?

Tags: языкознание

Примечание

1. В некоторых версиях христианства (например, в православии) термины "Слово" и "Христос" обозначают один и тот же объект.
2. Также существуют огнепоклонники, солнцепоклонники, идолопоклонники. А недавно объявилась группа лиц, которая поклоняется покойному попугаю Кузе.
3. Я не утверждал и не утверждаю, что во всех версиях христианства термины "Слово" и "Христос" обозначают один и тот же объект (добавлено 30.05.2014 г.)

Answer (score 1):

На рубеже нашей эры в Римской республике наметилась тенденция десакрализации традиционных религиозных культов. Люди узнавали новое и старые сведения переставали соответствовать знаниям людей об окружающем мире. На этой волне разрастались новые верования, как на основе  старых мифов (культы Геркулеса и Вакха), так и новые интерпретации религий соседей и покорённых народов (культ Исиды из Египта, митраизм на основе зороастризма и христианство на основе ветхозаветного иудаизма). Помимо того существовали различные гностические философы, в число которого входили и почитатели Логоса.

Гностики признали субстанциальное единство мысли и природы, субъекта и объекта – в представлении разумной *Пневмы* (духовного естества), или Логоса. Логос, как «понятие», есть нечто посредствующее между мыслящим субъектом и мыслимым объектом: этот термин обозначает и самую мысль, и то, что она мыслит, и самое отношение между формой и содержанием мысли. Поэтому "Логос" и был подходящим термином для выражения стоического монизма, точно так же как и представление пневмы в одно и то же время духовной и телесной являлось для него подходящим представлением.

Учение о Логосе повлияло на философию христианства, автор Евангелия от Иоанна по всей видимости именно под влияниям гностиков вставил в книгу учение о Логосе, т. ч. и знаменитое "Вначале был Логос и Логос был у Бога и Логос был Бог".

Популярности это христианству добавило, но встала проблема с тем, чтобы связать Ветхий и Новый завет, в частности как "Логос" Иоанна вставить в описание создания мира в "Бытие". Тут на помощь пришло учение о троице. "Логос" был объявлен ипостасью Бога, а конкретно Богом-сыном, который и творил мир через волю Бога-отца ("И **сказал** Бог, - "да будет свет". И стал свет."). Таким образом отождествление Логоса (слова) и Иисуса Христа и оказалось в христианстве, в том числе и православии.

Comment: 1. На рубеже нашей эры (5 марта 12 года до н.э.) принцепс Октавиан Август был объявлен верховным римским жрецом (Великим Понтификом) С тех пор и до 382 года н. э. каждый глава Римского государства исполнял полномочия Великого Понтифика.

2. В конце 20-х - начале 30 годов н. э. в [римской провинции] Иудее появилась группа лиц, которая объявила всех жрецов шарлатанами. В частности, эти лица утверждали, что каждый Великий Понтифик - шарлатан.

3. Сравните мой комментарий с Вашим ответом.

Comment: 1. Верно. Понтифики ведали общегосударственными религиозными обрядами. На  местах господствовали местные верования.
2. Вообще-то они появились несколько раньше, с 4 года до н. э., когда Иудея стала провинцией Рима, иудеи никогда не признавали древнеримскую религию.
3. Не вижу критериев для сравнения. И в моём ответе и в вашем комментарии описаны события одной эпохи.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы рассматривали объявление Октавиана Августа верховным римским жрецом как свидетельство того, что "в Римской республике наметилась тенденции десакрализации традиционных религиозных культов".

Comment: Факт наследования понтификства говорит лишь о разрушении республики (раньше понтифика избирали). А вот то, что Нерон в середине I века изнасиловал весталку и продолжал после этого править, о разложении религиозных нравов говорит красноречиво.

Comment: С точки зрения христиан [середины 1-го века], верховный шарлатан Нерон всего лишь совокупился с шарлатанкой, а именно жрицей [богини] Весты.

Answer (score 0):

Вы Галактион , я и всё окружающее в первую очередь , всего-навсего ставшее для нас таким обыденным - слово .. Так что трудно спорить с тем кто не понимает , что такое Бог или воспринимает его несколько иным  ...

Comment: Два вопроса: "Что есть божество христиан?" и "Кто есть божество христиан?"

Два ответа: "Слово есть божество христиан." и "Бог есть божество христиан."